# Significance of the figure above number of votes casted

Tags: discussion, support

Under sub-heading [*voters* (under users heading)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters), there's one figure **(104)**, in my case, above number of votes casted. What's the significance of this number?

[image]

Sorry for my poor paraphrasing of sentence, I am not native English speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the mouseover text:

> reputation this month: 104
>   total reputation: 915

Comment: I use mobile browser..

Comment: @Zenix You should use also full version of site, at least to get to know what you're missing otherwise...